# Change Navigation CSS in Wordpress with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress, navigation

I created a custom header navigation for my wordpress site for the homepage only. On all other pages, I am using the default theme navigation. However, on the homepage, after I scroll down past the custom nav I want to display default theme nav. I imagine that I could use javascript with a scroll function, so that once I am past, say 100px, the JS would change the css properties from display:none to display:block, or something to that effect.

I created a JS file:

```
    var fixed = false; $(document).scroll(function() {
            if( $(this).scrollTop() > 100 ) {
                if( !fixed ) {
                    fixed = true;
                    $('#menu-above-header-homepage').css({position:'fixed', display:'block'});
                }
            } else {
                if( fixed ) {
                    fixed = false;
                    $('#menu-above-header-homepage').css({display:'none'});
                }
            }
        });
```

I am calling the script from the file, homepage_nav.js to the homepage PHP template into the template header using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.brooklyn.cd/wp-content/themes/_eco/js/homepage_nav.js"></script>
```

I cannot get it to work though. Is there something wrong with my JS or the way that I am calling it into the PHP template file?

Answer (score 1):

You must put all inside a ready() function and to activate it on `window` scroll..

```
$(document).ready(function{
    var fixed = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > 100 ) {
            if( !fixed ) {
                 fixed = true;
                 $('#menu-above-header-homepage').css({position:'fixed', display:'block'});
            }
        } else {
            if( fixed ) {
                 fixed = false;
                 $('#menu-above-header-homepage').css({display:'none'});
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... still not working though with the change. I think it is probably an issue with how I am calling it into my PHP file. Perhaps there is a completely better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm also trying this javascript file, which I think is a lot cleaner, but still doesn't work.

`$(document).scroll(function() {$('#menu-above-header-homepage').toggle($(this).scrollTop() > 250); });`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed errors in the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 100 ) {
        $('#menu-above-header-homepage').css({position:'fixed', display:'block'});
    } else {
        $('#menu-above-header-homepage').css({display:'none'});
    }
  });
});
```

There is no need for fixed flag, also in case if you want to use it then rename that variable because that variable name 'fixed' is already a javascript property, rename it to something like 'isFixed'